# How to import structs from another package in Go

Tags: go, struct, import

I am trying to import the following struct into a separate package in Golang

```
package models
type Category struct {
    Title string
    Description string
    Parent *Category
    ParentId int
}
```

into `package controllers` as follows

```
import(
"website.com/Owner/blog/app/models"
)
func (c Category) Update(){
   //do something here
}
```

However, I get the error `unresolved type Category`
How should I go about importing a struct into a separate package with Go?

Comment: `func (c models.Category) Update() { // do something here }`

Answer (score 4):

You need to fully qualify your names: don't use `Category`, but use `models.Category`. The [doc](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations) there should get you started. You can do:

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}
```

Or:

```
import f "fmt"

func main() {
    f.Println("Hello")
}
```

Or ditch the qualification entirely (however, this is considered poor style: being able to see, at a glance, where some structure or function comes from is very handy when looking at code):

```
import . "fmt"

func main() {
    // Where does that come from ? Hard to know without 
    // intimate knowledge of the package
    Println("Hello")
}
```

One last thing you can do is to 'typedef' your remote structure for easier use locally:

```
import "website.com/Owner/blog/app/models"

type Category models.Category
```

Note however that it create a [new type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types), although with the same underlying type.